# What does "x is used prior to global declaration" mean? python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

Full code is here: http://pastebin.com/gG4JLNsX

Here's a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import random

def newGame():
 curveSetup()
 printStatistics()

def curveSetup():
 global curve 
 curve = random.randint(12,35)
 global lvl
 lvl = 1

def printStatistics():
 global expMax
 expMax = (lvl*curve)
 global lvl
 print "Character Level: "+str(lvl)

newGame()
```

Whenever I run my program, I'm getting an error saying

```
Warning (from warnings module):
 File "D:\Code\PyRPG.py", line 64
  global lvl
SyntaxWarning: name 'lvl' is used prior to global declaration
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? I've tried everything, I've looked around on similar questions asked on here and they are all either Python 3 or defined "x" before declaring that the variable itself is global. I've declared it is global before defining "x" therefore I don't see what is wrong with this.

EDIT: I've also defined lvl = 1 at the start, but it does not change anything at all. I've defined lvl at curveSetup() function which runs before everything else.

Comment: As a beginner you should *not* be investing time in learning Python 2. Those of us who still write in it do so because we have to support or migrate legacy code. As you have discovered, it is already harder to get help with problems specific to Python 2. This will only increase as daily use recedes and memory fades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `lvl` before declaring it global in `printStatistics()`, hence "name 'lvl' is used prior to global declaration".  It is a warning only, since having `global lvl` anywhere in the function makes `lvl` global.  The code still  works.  To get rid of the warning, move the `global` before use in that function:

```
 global lvl
 expMax = (lvl*curve)
```

In fact, `global lvl` is not required in this function at all.  It is only needed if you *modify* the global variable.  Here the value is only used in calculations without changing `lvl` itself.

Note that your program is horribly misusing globals.  As you can see, it makes the logic difficult to follow.  Global variables should be used rarely, and ideally for constants that don't change and won't require `global` declarations.  Prefer classes to hold state instead.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Does global mean that you only need it to edit it, or need it to view what the variable is?

Comment: @Civerion Only to edit. This is covered in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`global lvl` means that you use the `lvl` variable that is defined outside of the function. Therefore, `lvl` must exist outside of the function.

However, you never define `lvl`. You have to write somewhere something like `lvl = 0`, before any function referring to it is called.

Note that `lvl = lvl + 1` is **not** a definition of `lvl`.

Comment: I define level at curveSetup(), which runs before everything else. I also tried to put lvl = 1 at the start but that does not change anything.

Comment: That's not the problem. The warning arises purely from the contents of `printStatistics()`, which has `expMax = (lvl*curve)` _before_ `global lvl`.

Comment: @Civerion This is just what mwchase said: you write `lvl*curve`, so granted you defined `curve`, but you define `lvl` the line after, so it's still wrong. BTW, I recommend to declare all your global variables at the beginning of your function: `global lvl, curve`. Also, try to avoid using global variables. I mean, it's not wrong by itself, but there are generally some better ways, like passing these variables as arguments (with a default value if you don't want to change your function's code).